# Getting the labels of the column names (hmisc)

Tags: r, label, hmisc

I have used the `Hmisc` library to attach labels to column names, which you could do as follows.

[example](https://www.statmethods.net/input/variablelables.html)

```
library(Hmisc)
label(mydata$myvar) <- "Variable label for variable myvar"
```

Results:

[image]

It would be possible to set the labels for an entire `df` using a df called `Lbl` with in one column the names and one column the labels;

```
  Varcode Variables
1 P       Power
2 H       Happiness
```

as follows:

```
# set labels
for (i in seq_len(nrow(Lbl))) {
  Hmisc::label(df2[[Lbl$Varcode[i]]]) <- Lbl$Variables[i]
}
```

My question however is, if I have a labeled dataframe, how would I get them out (ie. reverse the command)?

Comment: `setNames(stack(lapply(df2, label))[2:1], c("Varcode", "Variables"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we extract the `labels` from each column and `stack` it to a data.frame with two columns

```
setNames(stack(lapply(df2, label))[2:1], c("Varcode", "Variables"))
```

Comment: Master where are you?